# Como pegar mais de uma propriedade em um array de objetos em JavaScript usando desestruturação

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um array de objetos contendo 5 objetos, ambos com propriedades x e y:

```
const objArr = [
  { 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, // OBJ0
  { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 }, // OBJ1
  { 'x': 3, 'y': 3 }, // OBJ2
  { 'x': 3, 'y': 4 }, // OBJ3
  { 'x': 4, 'y': 5 }  // OBJ4
]
```

Sei que posso pegar a propriedade x e y da seguinte forma:

```
const [ { x, y } ] = objArr;
```

Entretanto, eu só consigo armazenar o primeiro objeto:

```
console.log(x); // 1
console.log(y); // 1
```

Essa é a função que eu criei, ela funciona dessa forma, mas eu queria saber como reescrever ela usando desestruturação. Agradeço desde já.

```
function getCount([...objArr]) {

  let samePropCount = 0;

  for(let i=0; i<objArr.length; i++) {
    if (objArr[i].x === objArr[i].y) {
      samePropCount++;
    }
  }

  return samePropCount;
}
```

Comment: Pera um pouco, não entendi muito bem, sua função funciona, mas voce quer usar desestruturacao ao invés de `objArr[i].x`?

Comment: É mais pela questão de aprendizado sobre desestruturação

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas postei uma resposta. Analise ela

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas complementando, também existe o [for de iteração e desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao#for_de_itera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_e_desestrutura%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que é uma variação da declaração [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) que percorre [objetos iterativos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) desestruturando seus elementos:

```js
const objArr = [
  { 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, // OBJ0
  { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 }, // OBJ1
  { 'x': 3, 'y': 3 }, // OBJ2
  { 'x': 3, 'y': 4 }, // OBJ3
  { 'x': 4, 'y': 5 }  // OBJ4
]

//const getCount = (a)=> a.reduce((r,e)=>(e.x == e.y) ? r + 1: r, 0);
function getCount(a){
  let r = 0;                  //Declara e inicializa variável de resultado.
  //Para cada elemento da entrada os desestrutura em x e y...
  for(let {x, y} of a){
      r += (x === y)? 1: 0;   //...se x===y incrementa o resultado.
  }
  return r;                   //Retorna o resultado.
}

console.log(getCount(objArr))
```

Comment: Também é uma ótima alternativa. Muito obrigado pelo tempo de vocês e a atenção também!!

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, isto aqui `getCount([...objArr])` é irrelevante e redundante. Sua função deveria receber apenas `objArr`, pois ele já é um array e dessa forma `getCount([...objArr])`, o `objArr` dentro da função faz referência à `const objArr = [...]`. Use apenas `getCount(objArr)` para que a função seja pura e trabalhe apenas com o que lhe foi passado por parâmetro.

### Método 1

Usando o laço `for`:

```js
const objArr = [
  { x: 1, y: 1 }, // OBJ0
  { x: 2, y: 3 }, // OBJ1
  { x: 3, y: 3 }, // OBJ2
  { x: 3, y: 4 }, // OBJ3
  { x: 4, y: 5 }, // OBJ4
];

function getCount(objArr) {
  let samePropCount = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
    const { x, y } = objArr[i]; // desestruturamos aqui
                                // cada objArr[i] é um objeto {x: numero, y: numero}
    if (x === y) {
      samePropCount++;
    }
  }

  return samePropCount;
}

console.log(getCount(objArr));
```

### Método 2

Usando o laço `forEach`:

```js
const objArr = [
  { x: 1, y: 1 }, // OBJ0
  { x: 2, y: 3 }, // OBJ1
  { x: 3, y: 3 }, // OBJ2
  { x: 3, y: 4 }, // OBJ3
  { x: 4, y: 5 }, // OBJ4
];

function getCount(objArr) {
  let samePropCount = 0;

  objArr.forEach((obj) => {
    const { x, y } = obj; // desestruturamos aqui
                          // cada obj é um objeto {x: numero, y: numero}

    if (x === y) {
      samePropCount++;
    }
  });

  return samePropCount;
}

console.log(getCount(objArr));
```

### Extra

Existe uma maneira de desestruturar vários objetos desse array manualmente:

```js
const objArr = [
  { 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, // OBJ0
  { 'x': 2, 'y': 3 }, // OBJ1
  { 'x': 3, 'y': 3 }, // OBJ2
  { 'x': 3, 'y': 4 }, // OBJ3
  { 'x': 4, 'y': 5 }  // OBJ4
]

const [obj, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4] = objArr

console.log(obj, obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo o que eu queria, muito obrigado pelo tempo e atenção!!